# Flutter TextFormField not immediately in focus on onFocusChange

Tags: flutter

I'd like to detect TextFormField with `Focus(onFocusChange(bool))`, but when the TextFormField is in focus, the field isn't activated with the cursor as expected. I need to press tab again for the cursor to appear on the TextFormField. Any idea why the TextFormField doesn't get highlighted immediately on tab/next?

```dart
Form(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      ),
      Focus(
        onFocusChange: (bool inFocus){
          /// When tab is pressed, I expect the cursor to be on TextFormField
          debugPrint('TextFormField 2 in focus? $inFocus');
        },
        child: TextFormField(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

My current workaround on this issue is using a listener on FocusNode.

```dart
TextFormField(
  focusNode: _focusNode,
),
```

But this requires initialization and proper disposal.

```dart
final _focusNodePrice = FocusNode();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _focusNode.addListener(_onFocusChange);
}

@override
dispose(){
  super.dispose();
  _focusNode.removeListener(_onFocusChange);
  _focusNode.dispose();
}

/// Handles the quirks of TextFormField requirements
void _onFocusChange() {
  debugPrint('TextFormField inFocus? ${_focusNode.hasFocus}');
}
```

Here's a minimal repro of the issue.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FocusScope(
        child: Form(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Hint goes here 1'),
                  ),
                  Focus(
                    onFocusChange: (bool inFocus){
                      debugPrint('TextFormField 2 in focus? $inFocus');
                    },
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Hint goes here 2'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press tab or next the first time, the focus goes on the focus widget, then you press again and it goes on it's child, **so you can just remove the focus widget**

**edit:** if you need the Focus widget anyways, you can create a FocusNode and requestFocus as shown in your edited example below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FocusNode node1 = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FocusScope(
        child: Form(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Hint goes here 1'),
                  ),
                  Focus(
                    onFocusChange: (bool inFocus) {
                      if (inFocus) FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node1);
                      debugPrint('TextFormField 2 in focus? $inFocus');
                    },
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: node1,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Hint goes here 2'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Focus widget is TextFormField's parent because I need to detect the focus on TextFormField without `FocusNode.addListener()`. Is there any way to detect focus on TextFormField without FocusNode listener?

Comment: I have updated my answer by adding a FocusNode

Comment: also added if (inFocus) condition to request focus only when it should

Comment: Thanks `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode)` works. This solution answers the main issue. The only quirk in this solution is that you're unable to get back to the previous TextFormField with `Shift+Tab`. Focusing to the next TextFormField by hitting `Tab` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the better approach to my previous post would be to create a FocusNode for every field you want to check, and use **if (node1.hasFocus)** as a condition when needed.

So you don't need the Focus **widget** in this case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help you

```
FocusNode _passFocus;
FocusNode _repeatPassFocus;
String _newPass
```

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
         TextFormField(
             focusNode: _passFocus,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                fieldFocusChange(context, _passFocus, _repeatPassFocus);
              },
              initialValue: _newPass,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              onSaved: (val) => _newPass = val,  
            )
          TextFormField(
             focusNode: _repeatPassFocus,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              initialValue: _repeatNewPass,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              onSaved: (val) => _repeatNewPass= val,  
            ),
       ],
    );
```

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _passFocus = FocusNode();
    _repeatPassFocus = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
  }

void fieldFocusChange(
    BuildContext context, FocusNode currentFocus, FocusNode nextFocus) {
  currentFocus.unfocus();
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);
}

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _passFocus.dispose();
    _repeatPassFocus.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```